# Issue with Multithreading spin locks

Tags: operating-systems, synchronization

a spin lock solution to the critical path problem is shown below . my question is will this or will this not  result in starvation ?

```
    Thread A                Thread B
leave note A;           leave note B;
while (note B) {\\X     if (noNote A) {\\Y
    do nothing;             if (noMilk) { 
}                               buy milk;

if (noMilk) {                  }
    buy milk;           }
}                       remove note B;
remove note A;
```

let me illustrate my point ,if thread A and B are scheduled as shown wont that result in starvation ?

[image: sync issue]

note : those arrows are meant to indicate a cycle .

note: I'm following the online operating system course from Berkeley (http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-XXv-cvA_iCrnl0625nXp4GimjT-cv_1) .

In lecture 4 ,they talk about this as a correct solution to the critical path problem

Comment: Sorry .I'll re-edit the question to add the contents from the slide.

Answer (score 1):

Process B isn't looping; it runs and then quits. In other words, there won't be a second "leave note B" in your picture. There is a loop in process A (a *busy wait*, as it's called) and when process B removes its note, then execution will return to A's loop: A will check and see that there is milk so will remove its note and quit.

Comment: okay ,but what happens when b comes again and again  ? i.e a new instance of thread B.